# malloc adjacent block of memory?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I'm trying to figure out how many bytes in a block are taken up by the boundary tags. I have been told that when trying to `malloc` an adjacent block of memory, a "jump" will appear in assembly code, and I can use that to determine the size of the boundary tag. I've tried this:

```
int* arr = malloc(8);
arr++;
arr = malloc(8);
```

But there isn't any jump in assembly code. Am I "trying to `malloc` an adjacent block of memory"?

---

EDIT: I think he means a jump will appear between address value. I use the beginning of the second block of memory subtract the payload size of the first block. But I'm still confused, how could I `malloc` an adjacent block of memory?

Comment: Maybe "jump" mean the "change [jump] in address" value? The initial 'hint' provided by this other person seems questionable as it's presented..

Comment: There's no guarantee that two consecutive `malloc` calls will result in adjacent blocks. Also what do you mean by "jump in the assembly code"? Can you show some output of how you are checking that?

Comment: `arr++;` doesn't jump anything.  All it does is advance the memory address stored in `arr` by `sizeof(int)` number of bytes. That doesn't tell you anything about the allocated memory block.

Comment: You can't change what `malloc` does by incrementing the result it returns. `arr++` followed by `arr = malloc(8)` simply increments the first pointer you allocated then overwrites that with a pointer to a new block of 8 bytes of allocated memory.

Comment: @kaylum I now think he means jump between the address value. Do you know ways to malloc adjacent block of memory?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to make such a request to `malloc`. It' just not something that `malloc` was designed to do. Don't know where you got your original info from but it seems it is either taken out of context or just plain wrong.

Comment: Allocate twice as big a block as needed and use that pool.  That will guarantee adjacency.  By itself, 2 calls to malloc will not necessarily be adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're writing an actual memory allocator, you can't actually allocate two consecutive chunks of memory. If you want to see some pretty gnarly code which does this, have a look at the Illumos malloc https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/lib/libc/port/gen/malloc.c.

If you want to see how Illumos (and Solaris) handle the redzone between allocated blocks, you should trawl through https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/tree/master/usr/src/lib/libumem/common.

Answer (score 0):

The memory consumed by `malloc(3)` requires, for proper management of the actually used memory, of some structures that must be dynamically allocated also.  For this reason, many allocators just do allocate the space required for the management data adjacent to the block space dedicated to the user.  This makes that normally two consecutive junks of memory allocated by `malloc(2)` show some gap in their addresses.

There are other reasons to see gaps, one fundamental is that malloc normally gives you aligned memory addresses, so it is warranted that the data you store on that memory will be properly aligned.

And of course, there can be implementations (normally when heap allocation should be more robust in respect to buffer overruns) that the memory dedicated to storage of management data is completely unrelated and apart off the final given memory.  In this case you could observe no gaps between memory allocations on some cases.

Anyway, your code has serious bugs, let's see:

```
int* arr = malloc(8);
```

You had better here to acquire just the memory you need, using the `sizeof` operator, as in `int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr);` instead.

```
arr++;
```

this statement is useless, as you are going to overwrite the value of `arr` (the pointer) with new assignment statement after it from `malloc()`, so it is of no use to increment the pointer value.  You also are somewhat losing the returned value of the previous `malloc()` (which is essential in order to return the allocated memory, but read below).

```
arr = malloc(8);
```

Until here, you had the chance to `--arr` decrementing the value of `arr` in order to be capable of `free(3)` that block.  But this statement overwrites the value stored in `arr` so the previous pointer value is overwritten by the new pointer. Memory you acquired on the first malloc has no way to be accessed again.  This is what is commonly known as a *memory leak*, and is normally a serious error (very difficult to catch) on long run programs (like servers or system daemons).  The program allocates a bunch of memory in the inner part of a loop, that is not returned back with a call to `free(3)`, so the program begins growing and growing until it exhausts all the available memory.

A final note, I don't understand what did you mean with *malloc adjacent block of memory*.  Did you believe that incrementing the pointer would make `malloc()` to give you a special block of memory?

- First, malloc has no idea of what are you going to do with the pointer it gives to you.
- But also, it doesn't know anything about the variable contents of the pointer you are assigning to (you can even not store it in a variable, and pass it as another parameter to another functions) So there's no possibility for malloc to know that you have incremented the pointer value, or even the pointer location, from its body.

I cannot guess your interpretation.   It would be nice to know what has made you to think that you can control how `malloc(3)` selects the block of memory to give to you.  You have no control on the internals of `malloc()` You just specify **the amount of continous memory you want**, and mallocs provides it, giving you a pointer pointing to the start of that block.  You cannot assume that the next time you call malloc (with the same or different amount of memory) it will give you an adjacent block.  It just can be completely unrelated (above or below in memory) to the previous given block.  And you cannot modify that pointer, because you need it to call `free(3)` once you don't need the block anymore, with **exactly the same pointer value that `malloc(3)` gave to you**.  If, for some reason you modify the pointer, you need to restore it to the original value to be capable of calling `free(3)`.  Lack to do so, you'll probably crash your program at the next call to `free(3)`.

Answer (score -1):

I just see a memory leak.  Malloc 2 times into different vars 8 bytes of space and see if the difference is more than 8 bytes or 2 int.